# Unable to create user through API of Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, api, azure-devops

I'm a newbie with Azure DevOps API, and for a future migration case, I want to create new users on my Azure DevOps organization. The users is Azure Active Directory users.

So I tried to do it with that documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

The body of my API request look like this:

```
{
  "principalName": "test_user@company.com"
}
```

It return a status 201 (created) with this informations (for security reason i've put '.' on some lines):

```
{
    "subjectKind": "user",
    "metaType": "member",
    "directoryAlias": "test_user",
    "domain": "....",
    "principalName": "test_user@company.com",
    "mailAddress": "test_user@company.com",
    "origin": "aad",
    "originId": "....",
    "displayName": "test user",
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "....."
        },
        "memberships": {
            "href": "....."
        },
        "membershipState": {
            "href": "...."
        },
        "storageKey": {
            "href": "...."
        },
        "avatar": {
            "href": "...."
        }
    },
    "url": "....",
    "descriptor": "....."
}
```

But when I look on the organization users, I don't see any users who was created.

Did I miss something ? When I list users thourgh API it don't appear either...

Thanks in advance for your help.
P.S: It work well in the graphic UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've finaly solve my own problem...

The parameter **groupDescriptors** is mandatory in the HTTP request in order to activate the account.

The command should look like that:

```
https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{{COMPANY}}/_apis/graph/users?groupDescriptors=vssgp.{{GROUPDESCRIPTORS}}&api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

If you don't add the user to a group when you do the creation, he will not be able to connect.

Get the group descriptor:

```
https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{{COMPANY}}/_apis/graph/groups?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

Hope this will help someone else in the internet.